# Amazon FPS SDK ports for node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-fps

There appears to be [no node.js SDK libraries](https://github.com/awssum/awssum-amazon-fps/) for Amazon FPS (Flexible Payment Services).

Does anyone know of anything? It's brutally tedious to create from scratch.

I'm hoping the answer is here:

https://github.com/awssum/awssum-amazon-fps/

But compared to what you get, say with [Amazon's PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/code/PHP/4094948623747680), it doesn't look like it does much to help, but I may be missing something. I'll report back.

Comment: For those like me wasting their time looking for this - Amazon is retiring FPS June 2015 https://payments.amazon.com/help/201626250 - It's now Login and Pay with Amazon - found some js lib here https://github.com/recurly/pay-with-amazon

Answer (score 3):

I made a small lib for node to help with signing aws requests. hope you find this useful https://github.com/theRemix/aws_signature_utils_js